# Наложить картинку на Div

Tags: css

Есть div блок. Это карточка товара. Хочу сверху наложить картинку (скидка). Как правильнее все это сделать? Какие css свойства должны быть у картинки а какие у div Блока

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сделайте блок с карточкой товара `position:relative;` в него поместите Вашу скидку и сделайте её `position:absolute;`. Дальше - Можете внутри карточки товара перемещать скидку как захотите с помощью свойств `left`, `right`, `top`, `bottom`. Только иногда бывает необходимо подобрать `z-index` так, чтобы искомый элемент оказался *на*ложенным, а не *под*ложенным

Comment: супер, спасибо за разъяснение

Answer (score 0):

Например через `position: absolute;`. 1 вариант через псевдоэлемент, 2 вариант через добавление дочернего `span`:

```css
/* 1 вариант начало */
.product {
  position: relative; // что абсолютные дочерние блоки распологались относительно этого блока
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray; // для теста
}

.product.sale:after {
  content: "-20%";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  color: white;
  background: red; // сюда свою картинку прописываете
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  z-index: 10; // поднять значение, если перекрывается другими элементами, но не слишком высокое, что бы например не торчало поверх попапов
}
/* 1 вариант конец */

/* 2 вариант начало */
.product-2 {
  position: relative; // что абсолютные дочерние блоки распологались относительно этого блока
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightgray; // для теста
}
.sale-2 {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  color: white;
  background: red; // сюда свою картинку прописываете
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  z-index: 10; // поднять значение, если перекрывается другими элементами, но не слишком высокое, что бы например не торчало поверх попапов
}
/* 2 вариант конец */
```

```html
<div class="product sale">
    
</div>
<div class="product-2">
    <span class="sale-2">
        <!-- или сюда свою картинку прописываете через <img /> -->
        -30%
    </span>
</div>
```